# Connecting My Raspberry Pi To My Laptop Via Adafruit WiFi Dongle Without Internet

Tags: wireless-adapter, wifi-direct

I am running macOS 10.13.4 on my laptop and I am trying to connect it to my Raspberry Pi via wifi, I purchased a WiFi dongle from Adafruit *to increase the range of the WiFi on the Pi* by connecting it to one of the USB ports on the Pi. The dongle did not come with any instructions. Is it possible to SSH from my laptop to the Raspberry Pi without any connection to the internet, solely using the two devices and the dongle? My goal here is to eventually connect to the Pi via VNC. This is for a project that I am working on where I must connect to the Pi long range in the ocean to receive readings from an Arduino UNO. I have also purchased a WiFi receiver that extends the range another 150m, but it is yet to arrive. There will be no actual internet access in the process, until the readings are received, when the server receiving the content will post it to my domain for easy access to current readings from the Pi.

(I have two Pi's: one v2 model B, and another v3 model B)
(I'd preferably like to use Windows 10 for IoT on my Pi but any other OS will do)

Comment: (dongle is to improve range)* but thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is, "Yes, it is possible to SSH from my laptop to the Raspberry Pi without any connection to the internet, solely using the two devices and the dongle."

In general, what you need to set up is called a `wireless access point` (other names are used as well). This setup has been documented many times, so it would probably be redundant to do so here, but if you'll Google `wireless access point` you will find [many how-to guides](http://www.raspberryconnect.com/network). [Here's one that looks reasonable](https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/). You'll need to substitute the device name of the Adafruit wifi dongle for `wlan0`, and no doubt make some other adjustments, but this will get you close.

Try this, and if you hit any barriers, edit your question here to request help on specific points.

Comment: Will this work headless?

Comment: I'm trying to think of a funny clever answer to that question, but I can't, so, "Yes, it will work headless"   :)